# How can I use both safe and truncatechars method?

Tags: django, django-templates

I trying to solve this problem throughout the day. I want you to use the safe method so no one sees the HTML tags and also want to truncatechars to short the description. I want to do that if anyone wants to read that article must redirect to a detailed page of that article. I've created some dummy posts using faker.
When I try to create a post there some HTML tags shown on the home page it's because of Froala Editor so try to use a safe method to remove the tags. So use this way

```
<div class="description">
   {{post.description|truncatechars:150|safe}}                                  
</div>
```

After using this way my nothing is showing on my post description and also other posts also not showing even the sidebar also gone. After I remove the safe method it's back to normal. You check these images using the safe method and without a safe method.**Same thing happens when I use autoescape tag**
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `truncatechars` filter is not aware of HTML tags, what likely is happening in your case is that the closing tags are being truncated.

Lets say we have a variable `a = '<p>Hello</p>'` and we use `{{ a|truncatechars:5|safe }}`, what will happen? Well, The output would be `<p>He...`, The closing `p` tag got truncated and the HTML is now invalid!

Instead you want to be using the [`truncatechars_html` filter [Django docs]](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/templates/builtins/#truncatechars-html):

```
<div class="description">
   {{post.description|truncatechars_html:150|safe}}                                  
</div>
```